Solve function not returning the same output when it should
I'm trying to obtain an equation describing the intersection points of an arbitrary hyperbola with an ellipse centered at the origin. If I restrict the hyperbola to not have any horizontal translation, then I obtain a result which is not obtained by setting the corresponding parameter to zero in the general case. See the code below:
hyperbola1 = -x^2/(2  a) + (y - b)^2/(2 a) + d
hyperbola2 = -(x - c)^2/(2  a) + (y - b)^2/(2 a) + d

parabola = (x^2  (a - f)/(4  a  f)) + (y^2  (a + f)/(4  a  f))

yinx1 = Solve[hyperbola1 == 0, y]
yinx2 = Solve[hyperbola2 == 0, y]

intersection1 = Solve[g == parabola /. yinx1[[1]], x]
intersection2 = Solve[g == parabola /. yinx2[[1]], x]

Then, if I set $c=0$ in intersection 2, then intersection1 and intersection2 ought to be equivalent. However, for
intersection1 /. f -> 0.8 /. a -> 1.4 /. b -> -0.8 /. c -> 0 /. d -> -0.65 /. g -> 0.5
>>> {{x -> 0. - 1.28471i}, {x -> 0. + 1.28471i}, {x -> -0.982428}, {x ->0.982428}}

intersection2 /. f -> 0.8 /. a -> 1.4 /. b -> -0.8 /. c -> 0 /. d -> -0.65 /. g -> 0.5
>>> {{x -> 0. - 0.585366 I}, {x -> 0. + 0.585366 I}, {x -> 0. - 0.585366 I}, {x -> 0.+ 0.585366 I}}

Clearly, we do not recover the same numbers, meaning something is wrong. From other considerations, I have reason to believe that intersection1 is "correct", whilst something wrong occurs in intersection2.
How can I fix the issue to make sure that intersection2 returns the same values as intersection1 when $c=0$? Where is the error in the code occuring?

Is your variable "parabola" representing an ellipse? If so, why there is no constant term (corresponding to major or minor radius)?

@A.Kato, the variable "parabola" is a parabola, in (x,y,z), but becomes an ellipse when I consider the level curve z=g, where g is some constant. The major and minor axes are (a-f)/(4af) and (a+f)/(4af). All variables, except for x and y, can be thought of as constants in a particular calculation.

I see. You are considering a "cross section" of a parabolic surface. If you explain the three dimensional setting, more people might be interested in this question.
